# Trying to change the text with load but i'm not sure how to do that how i want

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I made a query that random a line from table in the database, and than from the information i'm print 2 parameters from the random line.

I want when I click on a button/text/something the query will run again and choose new random line but without refresh the page.

When you click on the button thats working but you see the "div thing" load again and thats ugly... i want only the text will loading again and i'm really dont know how to do that.

**my code:**
**the button:**

```
<span id="load_me"></span>
<button id="refresh">היית מעדיף לדלג?</button>
```

**the javascript/jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#load_me").load("question.php");

    $("#refresh").click(function() {
        $("#load_me").html("<h1>Loading...</h1>");
        $("#load_me").load("question.php", function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    })
    $("#refresh").click();
});
```

**the page "question.php":**

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `questions` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$RLine = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo '<div style="text-align: center"><a id="linky" href="stats.php?id='.$RLine['ID'].'&choice=Either1"><div class="button">'.$RLine['Question1'].'</div></a>';
echo '<a id="linky" href="stats.php?id='.$RLine['ID'].'&choice=Either2"><div class="button" style="background-color: rgb(0, 204, 68)">'.$RLine['Question2'].'</div></a></div>';
```

Comment: Please don't post questions which depend on links to 3rd party sites. Your questions need to be self-contained and answerable without any links.

Comment: you did it perfect, but i'm not understand why it's on hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after looking at your site and inspecting the server calls it seems you are returning a HTML every time. What you can do is return only 2 strings as a json and then place only that string into the div `I will leave this exercise  for you`.

Else if you cannot change the server side code and want this fixed. You can do this.

**Note :** This solution below is purely related to what your site HTML looks like, There are couple of HTML errors But I assume you will change it later.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#load_me").load("question.php");

        $("#refresh").click(function() {
            $('#load_me').find('font font').html("......");   // since you have a font element inside another font element         
            $("#load_me").load("question.php", function (data) {
                var tempDiv = document.createElement('div'); //create a temp div element
                tempDiv.innerHTML = data; //assign the response data into it
                $('#load_me').find('font:eq(0) font').text($(tempDiv).find('a:eq(0) div').html()); // extract the first div data and put into your font html
                $('#load_me').find('font:eq(2) font').text($(tempDiv).find('a:eq(1) div').html());    
                //font:eq(2) because font:eq(1) is the one inside font:eq(0)           
            });
        })
        $("#refresh").click();
    });
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: i hope i understand you good cus i'm not sure if...

anyway thats what i did:
http://pastebin.com/KtxQBDJu
and i have 2 places that i need to load when i clicked at the button, and i cant do that in 2 diffrents page cus the random line will not be the same...
and another thing: why did you said the html are not perfect? lol, "have errors"? can you give me exmple?

Comment: Like you have a font element and inside that another font element, You are returning a response from server with HTML content in that both the anchor tags have the same id, I didnt check other stuff But while working I saw these,

Comment: And wasn't my solution useful?? I tried this script on your site and saw it working fine. Let me know if you didnt feel its the solution

Comment: yes i know about the same id(thats not good) and i will fix this soon, like i said the site are not ready.
the script you gived me isn't working(or i did something wrong), when i replace him with my js code the 2 divs just deleted...
and i didnt understand what that need to do? to do only the text will load again?...

Comment: Can you share the site link so that I will take a look again and explain you how it will work.

Comment: a admin deleted the link... not me.... anyway: http://eitheril.tk/

Comment: @Tbjbu2 ok now do this. Open your site and open the console window and type `$("#refresh").unbind()` then hit enter. After this copy my `$("#refresh").click(function() {` function from the above answer and paste in console and hit enter. Now you have overridden your method with mine. Now go ahead and click on the buttons and see how it works

Comment: nv, find it, trying now...

Comment: which browser are you using?? If chrome then hit F12 and you can see a developer window in that choose the console tab

Comment: i'm with firefox, and now i'm not sure if thats it... i need to click ctrl+shift+k or something?.. ty for helping

Comment: right click your mouse and choose inspect element.. the developer window is available in all browsers..

Comment: ok i did it and thats working well, but why thats not working from the normal way?

Comment: Not sure, May be you didnt place it inside document ready or may be you made some mistakes while pasting.

Comment: you should replace your code with mine.

Comment: ok i fixed some things and now this working! ty

Answer (score 0):

try removing Line

```
 $("#load_me").html("<h1>Loading...</h1>");
```

Comment: how thats will help?